# Mesh has zig zag cracks after automatic weights

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am trying to rig a video game character model that I did not make. It's a God of War Raganrok model and I had to rig it myself and after doing automatic weights... i pose it and there are very weird cracks when the model moves. It's very strange.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably go to edit mode, select all and Merge by distance .... I'm not sure, but it could destroy UV map.

Comment: You are certainly correct about that. I merged by distance it worked. I think the UV Map is okay...

Comment: OK ...Than great ◉⁠‿⁠◉ ... Good luck with your project.